# NETSDK1136 "-windows" target platform exception happens when I dotnet publish, even though '-windows' suffix has been added to targetframework

Tags: .net-core, .net-5, .net-6.0

A common issue arises for folks upgrading from Core 3.1 or previous (netcoreapp3.1 in my case) to Core 5.0 or above (net6.0 in my case), if 'System.Windows.Forms' is referenced.  Once upgraded, you're given the exception: `NETSDK1136 The target platform must be set to Windows (usually by including '-windows' in the TargetFramework property) when using Windows Forms or WPF, or referencing projects or packages that do so.`

You can remove such references if unneeded, but otherwise, the solution is to append '-windows' to your .csproj "TargetFramework" tag.  Indeed, when I updated my TargetFramework to `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>`, the exception went away when I built my project in Visual Studio.  Yay.

However, when I build the project from the command line using `dotnet publish`, I still get this exception.  Does anyone know why?

I have cleared the Nuget cache.  I've closed VS and deleted the `bin` and `obj` folders.  I've tried running `dotnet publish` in Developer Command Prompt for VS 2021.  I've waved a dead chicken at the screen.  The exception continues to be given on the command line, even though the common solution indeed fixes the situation for Visual Studio.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#options it says -f|--framework <FRAMEWORK> Publishes the application for the specified target framework. You must specify the target framework in the project file.

Comment: Just to make sure - have you removed the System.Windows.Forms reference (and other "old" like System.Drawing, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you provided for fixing the exception in Visual Studio should also work when building the project from the command line using the `dotnet publish` command. If you are still encountering the exception after trying the steps you mentioned, it is possible that the issue is with the way you are calling the `dotnet publish` command.

To specify the target framework when using the `dotnet publish` command, you can use the `--framework` or `-f` option. For example, to publish a project targeting the .NET 6.0 framework for Windows, you can use the following command:

```
dotnet publish --framework net6.0-windows
```

Alternatively, you can use the shorter -f option like this:

```
dotnet publish -f net6.0-windows
```

If you are still encountering the exception after using the `--framework` or `-f` option, please provide more details about the exact command you are using and any error messages you are seeing. This will help me understand the issue better and provide a more specific solution.